# Can we use the adjective, "functional," to mean something has functions?

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning

I looked up the meaning of ***functional*** in dictionaries, and it seems like there are no examples of it being used to mean that something has functions. Because of that, I needed to ask you if ***functional*** can be used to mean that something has functions.

For example, can I say,

> The foreskin is a functional part of your body

or

> The foreskin is functional

to mean that the foreskin has functions? I am a person against circumcision. I use the word ***functional*** to describe the foreskin. I wonder if it is correct to use that adjective that way.

Comment: [Useful; serving a purpose, fulfilling a function](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/functional): *That sculpture is not merely artistic, but also functional: it can be used as a hatrack.*

Comment: Yes, it can be used that way. In fact I would say that this is the primary meaning. What do you think the other meanings are? Working properly, as opposed to broken?

Comment: @legatrix https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/functional None of the three definitions here is the same as my definition in the OP. That is why I needed to ask this question here.

Comment: Functional often means 'in functioning/ working condition'. The equipment is functional; it may not always mean here that 'the equipment has functions'.

Answer (score 2):

> Can we use the adjective, “functional,” to mean something has functions?

### Short answer - yes.

'Functional' is often used to mean that something which *normally* has a function is currently in 'working order', any many dictionary definitions may reflect this usage.

However, when it is less obvious or a lesser-known fact that something is functional, the word is used to show that it *is*.

Collins Dictionary states one definition as:

> *things are useful rather than decorative.*

This definition seems precisely what you expect it to mean in reference to a part of the human anatomy which has a function, or purpose.